# Does Linnik's approximation to Goldbach's problem also work for the power of 3, 5, 7, etc ?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, analytic-number-theory, goldbachs-conjecture

Linnik proved in 1951 the existence of a constant K such that every sufficiently large even number is the sum of two primes and at most K powers of 2.

Roger Heath-Brown and Jan-Christoph Schlage-Puchta in 2002 found that K = 13 works. This was improved to K=8 by Pintz and Ruzsa in 2003.

In above approximation, is there anything special about "powers of 2" ?
Is there any similar results for power of 3, or power of 5, etc ?

For example, can we say: every sufficiently large even number is the sum of two primes and at most K powers of 3 ?

Comment: You might just read the paper and find out. But you'll have to make a fundamental change to the statement of the problem, as right now parity prevents you from getting anything meaningful.